# Unable to install microsoft presidio-analyzer in Python 3.8

Tags: python, azure, pip

I am using Python 3.8 and its unable to install .whl from dist folder.
Presidio-analyzer is asking for `grpcio==1.21.0` but it not able install in Python 3.8.

[image: Installation error]

Comment: Can you try the latest  1.34.0 (later) or anything greater than 1.26.0 . something like this  `pip install grpcio==1.27.2`

Comment: Also, let me know whether you are using x64 bit of Python. Also, the OS version.

Comment: @SatyaV No its not working still.

Comment: Also, try upgrading the pip - `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and give it a shot. Also, help with the above details like OS and x64 Python ?

Comment: @JasonPan I am using windows 10 and there is no connection to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well with **Win10 + Python 3.8**. It looks like older versions of `grpcio` had [installation issues](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20604) with Python 3.8 on Windows but should be fine on Python 3.7 or 3.6.

Although the newer versions of grpcio (`v1.34.0` being the latest) have done away with those issues and install without errors on Python 3.8, there is a hardcoded dependency defined in presidio-analyzer's [setup.py](https://github.com/microsoft/presidio/blob/master/presidio-analyzer/setup.py#L31) on `v1.21.1`, removing which could fix the issue.

You can follow this GitHub issue for further updates: [Microsoft/presidio#378](https://github.com/microsoft/presidio/issues/378)

Answer (score 1):

grpcio is no longer a dependency of presidio-analyzer, so installing the latest version should work for you.